# Trigger jQuery ui date-picker automatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two text-boxes in which user have to select dates. I want to trigger second date-picker when the first date is selected. Please help.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/7SBPA/).

and this is the code :

```
 $('input[data-date="date"]' ).datepicker();
     $($('input[data-date="date"]' ).get(0)).change(function(e){
        console.log("triggered");
        $($('input[data-date="date"]' ).get(1)).trigger('focus');

 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your onSelect event in Jquery ui datepicker ,

```
onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#to" ).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    setTimeout(function(){
        $( "#to" ).datepicker('show');  //where 'to' is your second date
    },30);
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5D8zW/)